# How to find the number of system drives using R?

Tags: r

Using R, I want to find the number of system drives available on computer & external flash drives attached to it.

Comment: Learn to use capital letters. Does "no" mean "number"? Operating system? Have some respect for the audience, please. There is a frequently cited posting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is really not an R question, but one for the operating system. You can use `system` to spawn jobs to the system and get back information.

Assuming you are using Windows, I found this on [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/139899/see-available-drives-from-windows-cli).

```
sysdrivereport <- system("wmic logicaldisk get caption", intern = TRUE)
substr(sysdrivereport[-c(1, length(sysdrivereport))], 1, 1)

[1] "C" "D" "E" "F"
```